# d3.js support images per node

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm using [this](https://nylen.io/d3-process-map/graph.php?dataset=les-mis) graph in my private site to visualize products relationships and it works great.

I found [this site](https://linkedjazz.org/network/) with nodes as images. Trying to figure out how to refactor my current graph to support image per node.

Any help would be appreciated

**EDIT:** The problem with the "image" (and not `img`) is that I can't apply css on that. I'm using twitter bootstrap and trying to add class called `img-circle` (just adding `border-radius: 50%`) but it doesn't work with image. tried both:

```
   var nodeImage = node.append("image")
            .attr("xlink:href", function (d) { return d.image })
            .attr("height", function (d) { return d.height + "" })
            .attr("width", function (d) { return d.width + "" })
            .attr("x", function (d) {return -0.5 * d.width })
            .attr("y", function (d) {return -0.5 * d.height })
            .attr("class", "img-circle");
```

and:

```
var nodeImage = node.append("image")
        .attr("xlink:href", function (d) { return d.image })
        .attr("height", function (d) { return d.height + "" })
        .attr("width", function (d) { return d.width + "" })
        .attr("x", function (d) {return -0.5 * d.width })
        .attr("y", function (d) {return -0.5 * d.height })
        .attr("style", "border-radius: 50%;");
```

both doesn't work

**EDIT2:** DONE!

By adding the following line:

```
.attr("clip-path", function (d) { return "circle(" + (0.48 * Math.max(d.width, d.height)) + "px)"});
```

Comment: Tag is d3.js but title is 3d.js

Comment: @manassehkatz thanks, fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your files, I see:

```
graph.nodeRect = graph.node.append('rect')
    .attr('rx', 5)
    .attr('ry', 5)
    .attr('stroke', function(d) {
        return graph.strokeColor(d.categoryKey);
    })
    .attr('fill', function(d) {
        return graph.fillColor(d.categoryKey);
    })
    .attr('width' , 120)
    .attr('height', 30);
```

Instead of the `rect`s, you can append `image`s:

```
graph.images = graph.nodes.append('image')
    .attr('href', function (d) { return d.linkToThePicture })
    //.attr('foo', 'bar')...
```

It would be best if you stored the link to each picture (or relative file path) in the data (wherever you stored `d.name`). It also may be helpful to note that the example you provided the author uses images if type `.png`.

**Edit:** Even better, if you make the name of the picture match the names in the `data`, you have even less work to do!

```
graph.images = graph.nodes.append('image')
        .attr('href', function (d) {
            //the replacement takes out spaces
            return '/images/' + d.name.replace(/ /g, '') + '.png' 
        })
        //.attr('foo', 'bar')...
```

Comment: Cool! I'll try and update if works, thanks